# Is my project page affected if the directory is truncated to 1,000 files?

Tags: github, github-pages

For testing purposes, I’m using GitHub pages to host my HTML build game, but now I’m getting this limitation.

> Sorry, we had to truncate this directory to 1,000 files. 1,239 entries
> were omitted from the list.

I know it’s

> an artificial limitation of Github and only impacts viewing via the browser.

But I wonder if this truncation is gonna affect my project page? is my game going to be incomplete?

Comment: It's a limit in the webview on GitHub that lists your files. Your repository still contains all the files it should, so no, it will not impact anything other than your ability to view all the files in the GitHub repository browser.

Comment: What do you mean by "affect my project page"? That is just a page that displays the repository's content. Are you facing any **specific** problem?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen perfect, that's what I needed to confirm.

Comment: @NicoHaase no, dont have any problem yet, but my build is quickly growing in size and before continuing with github I wanted to make sure I wasnt going to be limited later. But has been clarified now.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Please post your answer as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this limitation when I wanted to import more than 1K files.
[image]

It's important to note that this limit is specifically for displaying files in the web view on GitHub. Your actual repository still contains all the files it should if you clone it. This limit won't impact anything beyond your ability to view all the files in the GitHub repository browser; If you encounter this limitation, you might consider restructuring your files.